# Hundreds of BLE devices advertising simultaneously

Tags: android, ios, testing, hardware

If an environment has many BLE devices (200 to 500) advertising within range of a mobile device that is scanning for BLE devices, will the mobile device be able to see all of the advertising BLE devices? Does anyone know of actual testing that has been done on this scenario and can provide results of the testing?

Comment: it depends on the range of the BLE devices.Suppose if BLE device range up to 70m, the mobile device within that range can detect that BLE device.

Comment: Refer this link https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/bluetooth_low_energy/f/538/t/143191

Comment: I would say it totally depends on the advertising interval. If you have the 20 ms advertising interval I guess most packets will collide and you will get many packet losses. I guess an advertising interval of at least 1 second would work better.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple answer I am afraid.  Assuming all advertizing devices are within a range (i.e. good RSSI), there are many factors affecting reception including: *duty cycle* of the scanner and *broadcast interval* of the beacons; you could also choose to use certain channels for groups of advertizers etc.  Say the scanner is running flat out (100% duty cycle) and you start from sporadic broadcasts on all channels, gradually increasing the rate at which adverts are broadcast.  At some point, you will hit a sweet spot -- increasing advert rate beyond will result in more collisions and poorer detection performance.  (It's like being in a room full of people, all talking over each other, all repeating the same utterance over and over again.)  The question is not so much "*how many advertizers?*" one can have but rather "*how reliably can the advertizers be heard within a certain timeframe?*" e.g. under which conditions can one detect an advertizer with 95% probability within 5 seconds.

If you can deploy multiple scanners (especially if they are spatially separated), then you will gain by collating their output.  Based on one particular experiment I carried out using two scanners: 4% adverts were received only by scanner #1, 2% only by scanner #2, and 4% were not received at all. So #1 scanner alone received 94%, #2 alone 92%, but together they received 96% of the adverts.

Here is some related work I found [Bluetooth beacon density maximum](https://blog.ruuvi.com/bluetooth-beacon-density-maximum-92bcb947ee99).